# RATIO_TO_REPORT rounded cents not accurate

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to force RATIO_TO_REPORT for generating rounded ratios to two cents? Sometimes if you manually round cents you will not receive the exact number of the sum of the records you based the ratio to report column and this is causing me a big issue in accounting reports in my company.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you show some code or at least a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that works out of the box, no. You're going to have to build your own procedure to allocate any differences in pennies.

The way my company does it is by the following algorithm:

1. Round values using your rounding method of choice, and compute the difference between the original value and the rounded value (this will always be less than a penny)
2. Sum the rounded values. Find the difference between the new sum and the "goal" sum. If the difference is positive (the new sum is higher), you need to remove pennies. If the difference is negative, you need to add pennies.
3. Since you (presumably) want to minimize differences between the unrounded and rounded values, depending on whether the difference between the new sum and the goal sum is positive or negative:

   a. Give whole pennies to the rounded values with the largest difference between unrounded and rounded values, until your sum matches the goal sum

   b. Take away whole pennies from the rounded values with the smallest difference between unrounded and rounded values, until your sum matches the goal sum

Answer (score 0):

The way I've found to accurate the 100% on the ratio is incrementing a case query to add the difference in the last row to reach the 100%.

Example with no accuracy:

```
Select 
  100 amount_to_Rate, 
  Data.amount, 
  Round(100 * Ratio_To_Report(Data.amount) Over(), 2) Ratio
From 
(
  Select 33 amount From dual
    Union
  Select 22 amount From dual
    Union
  Select 44 amount From dual
) Data;
```

[This ratio bring just 99.99 to total ratio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFqt8.png)

Example with the accuracy:

```
Select 
  Data_2.Amount_To_Rate,
  Data_2.Amount,
  Case
    When Data_2.Row_Num = Data_2.Max_Row_Num Then
      Data_2.Ratio + 
      Data_2.Amount_To_Rate - 
      Sum(Data_2.Ratio) Over(Partition By 1)
    Else
      Data_2.Ratio
  End
From 
(
  Select 100 Amount_To_Rate
        ,Data.amount
        ,Round(100 * Ratio_To_Report(Data.amount) Over(), 2) Ratio
        ,Rownum Row_Num
        ,Max(Rownum) Over(Partition By 1) Max_Row_Num
  From 
  (
    Select 33 amount From dual
      Union
    Select 22 amount From dual
      Union
    Select 44 amount From dual
  ) Data
) Data_2;
```

[The Ratio reaches the 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8hxY.png)